# Attempted to load class "DOMDocument" from the global namespace

Tags: php

Ok so i have set up a new symfony3 project using :

Vagrant----Virtualbox----PHP56----MYSQL55----UBUNTUTRUSTY64.

Everything was working correctly until i make a "composer update". I have this error message and i cannot do anything now

> Attempted to load class "DOMDocument" from the global namespace

So i found some proposed solution like "install php-xml" but it is already installed with newest version.

Does anyone have a solution or guide me to the right direction to find one

Many thanks

Nico

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Had the same issue with PHP 7.0.9, this worked:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Comment: sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: And if You have other PHP version, just change `php7.0-xml` to other `phpX.Y-xml` (for example `php7.1-xml`)

Answer (score 20):

You need to install the php-xml for your php version.

If you have php 5.6. you need to install php5.6-xml. It seems the newest version does not work for older versions.

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 5):

even sudo apt-get install php-xml works. it takes the current version.